# Error ingesting a flat file into Azure Data Lake Store using Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am getting the error below for certain time slices while using COPY activity in a data factory pipeline but at the same time it is also able to copy the file successfully to the specified data lake folder for some slices. I don't understand if this is an issue with the factory or lake or is it a data manager gateway communication failure. The pipeline creates 2 GUID folders underneath the specified lake folder and a 0KB "temp" file but the COPY activity fails with the error below.

```
FileWriter|Error trying to write the file|uri:https://bcbsne.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/Consumer/FlatFiles/2017071013/2a621c14-bdac-4cd6-a0d3-efba4a4526a0/5a3ac937-8176-469d-b6c6-ca738f8ab3a6/_tmp_test.txt-0.tmp?op=APPEND&overwrite=true&user.name=testUser&api-version=2014-01-01&offset=0&length=27&append=true,Content:
Job ID: 41ff39a9-f6e0-4b94-8f9d-625dec7f84de
Log ID: Error
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more details? Including the JSON for the datasets and activity. Thanks